# Training Neural Network loss not decreasing

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I wrote a bare-bones neural network using `python` as a way to test my understanding of neural networks. My issue is that the neural network loss does not decrease when it is trained. I used **least sum squares** as the loss function. Can someone with experience in neural networks please tell me where I went wrong.

**Details:**

I'm trying to train the network on a simple 2d data set where each point is part of one of two categories. My dataset is like the dataset used in this interactive neural network tool provided by tensorflow:

https://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=circle&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.61492&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false

I'm using one hidden layer with three hidden units, and an output layer with one unit. The loss function is **sum of squares**. I used the following sources to help me understand how back propagation works:

http://cs231n.stanford.edu/vecDerivs.pdf
http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture4.pdf

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_x = np.array([np.array([3,2,1,1,2,3]), np.array([4,6,6,1,1,1])])
data_x = data_x.transpose()
y_data = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1]) # 0 is blue #1 is red
weights = []
layers_hidden_units = [3,1]
caches = [0] * (len(layers_hidden_units) + 1) # list holding ai values and back propagation values
caches[0] = data_x
zs = [0] * len(layers_hidden_units) # list holding z values
bs = []
learning_steps = 10000
learning_rate = .001

def init_weights():
    for i in range(len(layers_hidden_units)):
        if (i == 0):
            bs.append(np.zeros(layers_hidden_units[0]))
            weights.append(np.random.rand(data_x.shape[1], layers_hidden_units[0]))
        else:
            bs.append(np.zeros(layers_hidden_units[i]))
            weights.append(np.random.rand(layers_hidden_units[i - 1], layers_hidden_units[i]))

init_weights()

def calculate_z(a_prev, W, b):
    Z = np.dot(a_prev, W) + b;
    return Z #shape is (m, a)

def sigmoid(z):
    sigmoid = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
    return sigmoid

def sum_of_squares_loss(y_hat):
    return np.sum(np.power(y_hat - y_data, 2))

def forward_propagation_step(a_prev, W, b, step):
    z_curr = np.dot(a_prev, W) + b
    a_curr = sigmoid(z_curr)
    zs[step] = z_curr
    caches[step + 1] = a_curr
    return a_curr

def forward_propagate(data_x):
    a = data_x
    for i in range(len(layers_hidden_units)):
        a = forward_propagation_step(a, weights[i], bs[i], i)
    print("sum of squares loss: " + str(sum_of_squares_loss(a)))
    return a;

def backpropagate_step2(z_prev, W, a_prev, back_value, b):
    dz = np.multiply(sigmoid(z_prev) * (1 - sigmoid(z_prev)), back_value)
    back = np.dot(dz, W.transpose())
    w, b = gradient_descent2(a_prev, z_prev, dz, back_value, W, b)
    return (w, b, back)

def gradient_descent2(a_prev, z_prev, dz, back_value, W, b):
    dW = np.dot(a_prev.transpose(), dz)
    db = dz
    W = W - learning_rate * dW
    b = b - learning_rate * db
    return (W, b)

def backpropagate2():
    a_last = caches[len(caches) - 1]
    z_last = zs[len(zs) - 1]
    back = 2 * np.sum(y_data - a_last)
    for i in range(len(caches) - 2, -1, -1):
        W, b, back = backpropagate_step2(zs[i], weights[i], caches[i], back, bs[i])
        weights[i] = W
        bs[i] = b

def train():
    for i in range(learning_steps):
        forward_propagate(data_x)
        backpropagate2()

def predict():
    x_value = np.array([np.array([1]), np.array([5])])
    x_value = x_value.transpose()
    return forward_propagate(x_value)

train()
prediction = predict()
print("prediction: " + str(prediction))
print("weights: " + str(weights))
print("b's: " + str(bs))
```

**Edit**

Output of the loss function over each training step:

```
sum of squares loss: 9.41904563854931
sum of squares loss: 9.466209959933774
sum of squares loss: 9.521526062849716
sum of squares loss: 9.586899865148004
sum of squares loss: 9.664794367157919
sum of squares loss: 9.758420389666265
sum of squares loss: 9.871998308092504
sum of squares loss: 10.01111579994052
sum of squares loss: 10.183210868157662
sum of squares loss: 10.398206323346686
sum of squares loss: 10.669295283053922
sum of squares loss: 11.01378465075701
sum of squares loss: 11.453638064297865
sum of squares loss: 12.014673540964441
sum of squares loss: 12.72180795275546
sum of squares loss: 13.585099304548
sum of squares loss: 14.571325340888313
sum of squares loss: 15.575875071643217
sum of squares loss: 16.450858359675404
sum of squares loss: 17.09492556599039
sum of squares loss: 17.50379115136118
sum of squares loss: 17.737928687252197
sum of squares loss: 17.86441528900727
sum of squares loss: 17.93065857787634
sum of squares loss: 17.964762961628182
sum of squares loss: 17.982154959175745
sum of squares loss: 17.99097886266222
sum of squares loss: 17.995443731332028
sum of squares loss: 17.997699846969052
sum of squares loss: 17.998839078868475
sum of squares loss: 17.99941413509295
sum of squares loss: 17.999704357817745
sum of squares loss: 17.999850815993767
sum of squares loss: 17.999924721397637
sum of squares loss: 17.99996201452985
sum of squares loss: 17.999980832662573
sum of squares loss: 17.99999032824638
sum of squares loss: 17.999995119680737
sum of squares loss: 17.999997537416142
sum of squares loss: 17.999998757393232
sum of squares loss: 17.999999372987293
sum of squares loss: 17.99999968361277
sum of squares loss: 17.999999840352714
sum of squares loss: 17.999999919442843
sum of squares loss: 17.9999999593513
sum of squares loss: 17.999999979488887
sum of squares loss: 17.999999989650206
sum of squares loss: 17.99999999477755
sum of squares loss: 17.99999999736478
sum of squares loss: 17.999999998670287
sum of squares loss: 17.99999999932903
sum of squares loss: 17.999999999661433
sum of squares loss: 17.999999999829164
sum of squares loss: 17.999999999913797
sum of squares loss: 17.999999999956504
sum of squares loss: 17.99999999997805
sum of squares loss: 17.999999999988926
sum of squares loss: 17.99999999999441
sum of squares loss: 17.99999999999718
sum of squares loss: 17.99999999999858
sum of squares loss: 17.999999999999282
sum of squares loss: 17.999999999999638
sum of squares loss: 17.999999999999815
sum of squares loss: 17.999999999999908
sum of squares loss: 17.99999999999995
sum of squares loss: 17.99999999999998
sum of squares loss: 17.999999999999993
sum of squares loss: 17.999999999999993
sum of squares loss: 18.0
sum of squares loss: 18.0
sum of squares loss: 18.0
sum of squares loss: 18.0
sum of squares loss: 18.0
sum of squares loss: 18.0
```

**Edit 2**

Input data:

```
3,4 -> 0
2,6 -> 0
1,6 -> 0
1,1 -> 1
2,1 -> 1
3,1 -> 1
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post some actual data that you processed in addition to the tensorflow link.

Comment: It's pretty hard to debug a neural network just by reading source code. Are you tracking your loss function at set time steps? Can you show what the loss function is actually doing? Have you checked your gradients by performing gradient checking? Lastly, usually with binary classification, we use the cross entropy loss rather than a mean squared error loss. You can use a mean squared loss, it shouldn't break the neural net, but I just wanted to let you know that cross entropy is far more popular in this case.

Comment: @enumaris I added in what the loss function is doing over each training step

Comment: @JagrutSharma I hard coded the data. I added it separately to the post as well

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be in the function backpropagate_step2 in this line:

```
dz = np.multiply(sigmoid(z_prev) - (1 - sigmoid(z_prev)), back_value)
```

It should be

```
dz = np.multiply(sigmoid(z_prev)*(1 - sigmoid(z_prev)), back_value)
```

because the derivative of sigmoid(x) is sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x)) and not sigmoid(x) - (1-sigmoid(x)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!! Unfortunately, I still see the same behavior. I'm not sure why